# Is Platy really a Platypus?

Tags: sabagebu

In *Sabagebu!* episode 4, Mokarin tries to find out where Platy comes from. Everyone thinks that Platy is a platypus but they aren't able to confirm it since it doesn't do anything a platypus does.

[image: Platy]

So my question, is it actually a Platypus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so, although it's never revealed - the name Platty (and in Japanese Kamo - short for Kamonohashi [platypus] ) and his appearance is pretty indicative of it.

If we use the [Duck Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test):

> if it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

Platty:

- Looks like a platypus
- We don't really get to see Platty swim, but he does enjoy a hotspring - where platypuses can reside. [article about an investigation of Platypuses in Lake Kinrin hotspring water](http://www.ed.oita-u.ac.jp/kykenkyu/bulletin/kiyou/takahama32-1.pdf)

[image]

- He sorta sounds like a platypus https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsd7ZfdZcNU , but it's more of a quack noise.

**Conclusion:** Maybe? (I don't think we're supposed to know)